# PM2 - Is this considered a good practice

Tags: node.js, pm2

In my project I have several servers which run NodeJS applications using PM2, those were not created by me. I am not that familiar with the PM2. Now I need to start a new server, which is simply a CRON process that queries an ElasticSearch instance.
There are no routes or anything in it, just a CRON with some logging.
Here is my dilemma. I have played with PM2 and I become somewhat familiar with what is it, and what it does. But the question is how shall I run it?

The previous projects do have PM2 config.json with many parameters, and they are started in cluster mode (handled with Nginx), and when I start them I see all process's becoming daemons. But in my case I don't need that. I just need it to run as a single service.

In other words if I use the configuration file to run the PM2, I see it spawned in cluster mode, and it creates chaos as my CRON is fired many times. I don't need that. If I start it in Fork mode, it also spawns instances, but all of them die, except one (due to which they are using same port). I also don't need that.
I just need single service.

I managed to run the my CRON app.js with the singe line, simple as:
PM2 start app.js. It runs in single thread, and I can see it's info with PM2 status. All fine.

If I run it with the single line(as in my case), is it considered ok? Based in my knowledge if I use config.json, it will always run it in fork or cluster.
Is it ok to run it in single line, or do I need still to use a config.json file.

Comment: Should your process stop when the query is finished?

Comment: No. It runs indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one process to be run, as is the case, you're doing the right thing.